# How to disable column move in locked grid from normalGrid to locked

Tags: extjs

I'm creating some not standart grid panel with locked columns. So I have some grid with locked and not columns. By default I can move this columns(change them order). So when grid panel with locked column is render it creates lockedGrid(with locked columns) and normalGrid(with normal columns) and I can move column from normal to locked.

It works fine but I need to disable ability move column to locked grid but leave ability to move columns inside normalGrid.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the columnmoved event to move the column back to its original position?

```
this.getColumnModel().on('columnmoved',function(cm,oldindex,newindex) {
    cm.moveColumn(newindex,oldindex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All normal columns should have:

```
lockable: false
```